# How to run minikube dashboard using systemctl

Tags: minikube, systemctl

I want to use the `systemctl` command to run `minikube dashboard` and `kubectl proxy` to make it easier for me to access dashboard from the external environment.
Here is my configuration:

/homw/wj/minikube-dashboard.sh

```
#!/bin/zsh
MINIKUBE_HOME=/home/wj/.minikube
# /usr/bin/minikube kubectl -- proxy --port=8000 --address='192.168.31.15' --accept-hosts='^.*' &
/usr/bin/minikube dashboard --url
```

/homw/wj/minikube-dashboard-proxy.sh

```
#!/bin/zsh
MINIKUBE_HOME=/home/wj/.minikube
/usr/bin/minikube kubectl -- proxy --port=8000 --address='192.168.31.15' --accept-hosts='^.*'
```

/lib/systemd/system/minikube-dashboard.service

```
[Unit]
Description=minikube dashboard

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/wj/minikube-dashboard.sh
RemainAfterExit=no
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

/lib/systemd/system/minikube-dashboard-proxy.service

```
[Unit]
Description=minikube dashboard proxy

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/wj/minikube-dashboard-proxy.sh
RemainAfterExit=no
Restart=always
Wants=minikube-dashboard.service
After=minikube-dashboard.service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I run `systemctl start minikube-dashboard.service`，

I got the following error:

```
● minikube-dashboard.service - minikube dashboard
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/minikube-dashboard.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Fri 2023-10-13 02:43:59 CST; 7s ago
  Process: 3257785 ExecStart=/home/wangjin/minikube-dashboard.sh (code=exited, status=85)
 Main PID: 3257785 (code=exited, status=85)

Oct 13 02:43:59 wj-c7-01 systemd[1]: Unit minikube-dashboard.service entered failed state.
Oct 13 02:43:59 wj-c7-01 systemd[1]: minikube-dashboard.service failed.
Oct 13 02:43:59 wj-c7-01 systemd[1]: minikube-dashboard.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Oct 13 02:43:59 wj-c7-01 systemd[1]: Stopped minikube dashboard.
Oct 13 02:43:59 wj-c7-01 systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for minikube-dashboard.service
Oct 13 02:43:59 wj-c7-01 systemd[1]: Failed to start minikube dashboard.
Oct 13 02:43:59 wj-c7-01 systemd[1]: Unit minikube-dashboard.service entered failed state.
Oct 13 02:43:59 wj-c7-01 systemd[1]: minikube-dashboard.service failed.
```

I run `journalctl -u minikube-dashboard` command, Get the following information:

```
Oct 13 02:43:59 wj-c7-01 systemd[1]: Started minikube dashboard.
Oct 13 02:43:59 wj-c7-01 minikube-dashboard.sh[3257785]: * Profile "minikube" not found. Run "minikube profile list" to view all profiles.
Oct 13 02:43:59 wj-c7-01 minikube-dashboard.sh[3257785]: To start a cluster, run: "minikube start"
Oct 13 02:43:59 wj-c7-01 systemd[1]: minikube-dashboard.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=85/n/a
Oct 13 02:43:59 wj-c7-01 systemd[1]: Unit minikube-dashboard.service entered failed state.
Oct 13 02:43:59 wj-c7-01 systemd[1]: minikube-dashboard.service failed.
Oct 13 02:43:59 wj-c7-01 systemd[1]: minikube-dashboard.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Oct 13 02:43:59 wj-c7-01 systemd[1]: Stopped minikube dashboard.
Oct 13 02:43:59 wj-c7-01 systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for minikube-dashboard.service
Oct 13 02:43:59 wj-c7-01 systemd[1]: Failed to start minikube dashboard.
Oct 13 02:43:59 wj-c7-01 systemd[1]: Unit minikube-dashboard.service entered failed state.
Oct 13 02:43:59 wj-c7-01 systemd[1]: minikube-dashboard.service failed.
```

How should I deal with this mistake? Thank you.

I tried to get the error message from the search engine. Here are the results I got：[Received error: Profile "minikube" not found. Run "minikube profile list" to view all profiles. #15603](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/15603) and [How can I access minikube profile with different users on Linux？](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/15584)

Comment: I found an error message in the log:`Oct 13 02:43:59 wj-c7-01 minikube-dashboard.sh[3257785]: * Profile "minikube" not found. Run "minikube profile list" to view all profiles.`. Because when I run the `minikube` command locally, I use the `.minikube` directory under the account `wj`. When I expect to run `minikube` through the `systemctl` command, I use the root account. Therefore, I added two lines of configuration `User=wj Group=wj` to the `[Service] `option of the two `.service` files, it works now.